# Display of indication in Textview

Tags: android, textview

In my application  i have 1 list view  with 4 text views as column wise.I am showing data from database,in that some data have some recurrence value and other will not.So i have to have a indication image for that data which have recurrence.So i have an idea to place some small image at the end of 2nd Text view  in list view.If i tried by placing some text view in xml and set some image for that means the other textview(textview 3 ,4) is also misplaced.Does anybody have anyidea to do this.I also tried for spannableimage but not getting desired result.Thanks in advance.

What i have:
My list view:

```
31/7/2012 | gfdhh  |  78  |   78
```

What i want is :

```
31/7/2012  | gfdhh* | 78  |78.
```

My code:(for listview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Layout1"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:paddingTop="4dip"
     android:paddingBottom="6dip"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     >     

     <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"      
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        /> 

     <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

     <TextView android:id="@+id/text3"          
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>




     <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

       <TextView android:id="@+id/text5"            
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        />
       <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text7"           
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        />

          <TextView android:id="@+id/text9"         
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"            
         android:visibility="gone"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

The spannable image code i tried for:

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_DESC))); 
                                Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.up); 
                                d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight()); 
                                ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE); 
                                ss.setSpan(span, 0,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_DESC)).length() , Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); 
                                text3.setText(ss);
```

Comment: And what problem are you facing with this Spanned text?

Comment: Only the image is showing(R.drawable.up),not with the text...

Comment: Imran Khan y u deleted your answer???